# a Ramsey-type question

Tags: co.combinatorics

This question is related to  [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52825/coloring-mathbb-zk)  but feels more Ramsey-type, so perhaps it is easier. Let $S$ be a finite set, $|S|=k$. Suppose we color all subsets of $S$ in $1000$ colors. What is the maximal (in terms of $k$) guaranteed length $l=l(k)$ of a monochromatic sequence of pairwise different subsets $A_1,A_2,..., A_l$ such that $|A_i\setminus A_{i+1}|+|A_{i+1}\setminus A_i|\le 2$ for every $i$? Clearly if $A$ is a subset of $S$ such that  all 2-element subsets of $A$ are monochromatic, then $l(n)\ge |A|-1$ (there  is a sequence of 2-element subsets of $A$ which satisfies the above property). So $l(k)$ is at least as big as the corresponding number from the Ramsey theory. Is it much bigger? The number 1000 is of course "any fixed number".

**Update 1**  Fedor and Tony showed below that $l(k)\ge k/1000$. Thus only the first question remains: What is $l(k)$? Is it exponential in $k$, for example?

**Update 2**  Although the question I asked makes sense (see Update 1),  I realized that it is not the question I meant to ask. Here is the correct question. Same assumptions: $|S|=k$, 1000 colors. We consider monochromatic sequences of pairwise different subsets ${\mathcal A}=A_1,A_2,...,A_l$, where $|A_i\setminus A_{i+1}|+|A_{i+1}\setminus A_i|\le 2$. For each of these sequences we compute $\chi({\mathcal A})=|A_1\setminus A_l|+|A_l\setminus A_1|$. Now the question: what is the maximal guaranteed $\chi({\mathcal A})$ in terms of $k$, call it $\chi(k)$? By Ramsey, this number grows with $k$. Indeed if we color just $s$-element subsets, we will be able (if $k\gg s$) to find a subset of size $2s$ where all subsets of size $s$ are colored with the same color;  then we can find a monochromatic sequence of subsets of size $s$ with the above property and $\chi=2s$ because the first and the last subsets in that sequence are disjoint. The question is what is the growth rate of $\chi(k)$. The question is motivated by Justin Moore's answer 
 [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37449/covers-of-z-infty)

Comment: A natural assumption is that the A_i are all required to be distinct.  Another is if A_i = A_j, then either i=j or A_i+1 is not equal to A_j+1.  Are you interested in no cycles or in a long Eulerian path?  Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.12

Comment: @Gerhard: You are correct. 

Comment: I'll take that as meaning that both versions are of interest.  I am struggling to remember a MathOverflow question which used the term "2-connected" to mean roughly that points were within distance 2 of one another.  Although the enumeration problem discussed was different, you might still find it of interest in tackling this problem.  When I find it, I'll post a link to it.
Gerhard "Email Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.07.12 

Comment: @Gerhard: These were my questions, I refer to them here. 


Comment: My memory says this question that I am trying to remember was not one of yours,  It was trying to compute something like the expected size of a 2 neighborhood of a graph, and had a reference whose name I am also trying to remember.  Unless this triggers someone else's memory, I'n afraid we will have to let me continue the struggle.  Gerhard "Connected Associative Memories Work Better" Paseman, 2011.07.12 

Comment: What's known about the continuous version? That is, if you cover the sphere $S_n$ with m closed sets, what can be said about the structures that must be contained in at least one of the sets? If m=n+1 then we get two antipodal points, but what if m=1000? It seems that one ought to get much more. At the moment I don't even see a counterexample to the assertion that if m=n then you get a path from a point to the antipodal point, though that seems a bit optimistic. Am I asking about the Lusternik-Schnirelmann capacity of projective space or something like that? 

Comment: What is  "Lusternik-Schnirelmann capacity"? I thought that  Lusternik-Schnirelmann category is about covers by open sets. The continuous version does make sense of course. In fact an interesting problem is about coloring of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and existence of monochromatic 2-paths (in the $l_1$-metric) of arbitrary diameter. 

Comment: Found [it](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67451/number-of-2-connected-subsets-in-the-hypercube).  The poster mentions Sapozhenko.  I am less sure how applicable this problem is, but it may still be of interest.  Gerhard "Another Load Off My Mind" Paseman, 2011.07.12

Comment: @Gerhard: He considers the same graph: vertices are subsets of $S$ with two subsets connected if their symmetric difference has at most 2 element. So it may be related indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, I meant category. The rough idea I had in mind was that if you cover the $n$-sphere with $m$ open sets, then it would be nice to show that one of them was non-trivial in some topological sense. The trouble is, they're all contractible, but perhaps one could hope that one of them intersected with minus itself is not contractible when considered as a subset of projective $n$-space. That's not quite the same as Lusternik-Schnirelman category but it seems to be in a similar ball park and I don't rule out some way of getting from one to the other.

Comment: By the way, I find this cluster of related questions you are asking very appealing. (My attention was first drawn to them by Noga Alon.)

Comment: I know that Noga Alon became interested in these questions (after my talk at a conference in Cambridge last January). 

Comment: Yes it was then.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof of a very weak upper bound for $l(k)$.  Consider the colouring of $2^S$ where each set is coloured by its size (mod 1000).  A good monochomatic sequence must consist of sets of the same size.  Thus we obtain $l(k) \leq \binom{k}{k/2}$.

However, we can be a bit smarter.  Instead of colouring *all* $i$-subsets of $S$ with the same colour, we can use 333 colours and still guarantee that a good monochromatic sequence must use sets of the same size.  Thus, we are lead to the problem of 333-colouring $\binom{S}{i}$ to minimize the length of a good monochromatic sequence inside $\binom{S}{i}$.

Answer (score 2):

It is much bigger for sure, even if we restrict two subsets of cardinality 2 (call them edges). You need monochromatic path of length $\ell$. Take the color with at least $k(k-1)/2000$ edges of this color, consider only them. Consider the maximal path in our graph. It has length at most $l-1$. Hence it endpoint (both of them) has degree at most $l-1$. Remove it and repeat (or use induction). We get that our graph has at most $(l-1)k$ edges. So, $k(k-1)/2000\leq (l-1)k$, $l\geq (k-1)/2000+1$.

Comment: By considering the colouring of the singletons and applying Pigeonhole we get $l \geq k/1000$.  


Comment: @Fedor and Tony: this answers the second question, $l(k)\ge k/1000$. But what is the growth of $l(k)$. Is it exponential or polynomial or something in between? 